# Validation request cancellation?

Tags: validation, swiftui

I'm getting this message in the console window when running a SwiftUI iOS 15 app on an iPad simulator in Xcode 13.2 when I change the orientation of the iPad.  This reconfigures a List and a plot to be a vertical stack or a horizontal stack depending on the geometry reader width and height of the view.

2022-02-18 15:31:51.214810-0800 Mode Analyzer-1D[61895:2062036] [Assert] Somehow we ended up in _validateCurrentFocusedItemForAppearingEnvironment even though there is no focused item. We should have cancelled the validation request in that case.

How do "we" cancel the validation request? Let alone what is a validation request?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I know it's not helpful, but I'm having the same problem...

Comment: I'm not seeing this anymore but can't find a specific change I made.  Cleaned up a lot of things in the app, however

Comment: I’m not either anymore, but I also can’t really say what exactly I did that made it go away. I just kept working on the feature I was developing and at some point, the warning was gone…

Comment: Happening in my Swift 1.0 app but there's an Apple Developer forum saying this message "went away in iOS 16"